# How to handle "out of balance" situation in java-me sms app?

Tags: java-me, sms

A j2me app is sending sms. Now SIM card in the mobile phone is prepaid and is out of balance,
So app cant send the sms. Do we get any exception in this case ???
As far as I know it gives IOException, I have handled the same but it is not working...